# "This operator is odd under parity"

Tags: operators, parity

In problem 8.10 of Schaum's Quantum Mechanics they
say:

"We see that under the parity operator $r \rightarrow r$,
$\theta \rightarrow \pi - \theta$ and $\phi \rightarrow
\pi + \phi$
.. since $\frac{d}{d\theta} \rightarrow -\frac{d}{d\theta}$ and
$\frac{d}{d\phi} \rightarrow \frac{d}{d\phi}$,
it follows that the operators $\hat{L}_\pm$
are not affected by the parity operation."

(Here $\theta$ is the $z$-axis spherical angle and $\phi$ is the
azimuthal spherical angle.)

Another source, http://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~valenti/SS14/QMII_2014_chap3.pdf,
also refers to this idea of an OPERATOR being  "odd"  under parity.

Do the operators really change?  If you represented the $\frac{d}{d\theta}$
operator for example  "under the parity operation"  (what does that mean?)
as a matrix, wouldn't it be the exact same matrix?  It's just that the
input wavefunction that is being input as argument to the $\frac{d}{d\theta}$
operator has had all its $+$ and $-$ signs flipped  (from the perspective
of $x y z$ coordinates)
<strike>messed around with</strike>, so naturally the
$\frac{d}{d\theta}$  outputs $-1$ times its result.  Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you represented the ddθ operator for example "under the parity operation" (what does that mean?) as a matrix, wouldn't it be the exact same matrix?

When we talk about an operator undergoing some unitary transformation, be it spatial inversion, rotation, time reversal, etc., we are saying

$$U^{-1}AU = \,\,?$$

Saying an operator is odd/even means

$$U^{-1}AU = \pm A$$

with $+$ for even and $-$ for odd.

When you look at the matrix elements of a transformed operator,

$$\langle \alpha | U^{-1}AU | \beta \rangle$$

you can see that these are not the same as those of the original operator,

$$\langle \alpha | A | \beta \rangle$$

So the matrix is *not* the same.

> It's just that the input wavefunction that is being input as argument to the ddθ operator has had all its + and − signs flipped

That's a valid way of looking at it as well. Instead of viewing $\langle \alpha | U^{-1}AU | \beta \rangle$ as some new operator $A' = U^{-1}AU$ acting on the old states, you can see it as $A$ acting on the transformed states $\langle \tilde \alpha | = \langle \alpha | U^{-1}$ and $| \tilde \beta \rangle = U | \beta \rangle$. I'll stress that the matrix is still not the same, provided you're using the same basis in either case.

To illustrate this point, let's consider the expectation value of an operator $A$ - which commutes with the position operator - after a parity transformation. We have

$$\langle A' \rangle = \langle \Psi | \Pi^{-1}A\Pi | \Psi \rangle = \int d\mathbf{x'}d\mathbf{x''} \langle \Psi | \Pi^{-1} | \mathbf{x'} \rangle \langle \mathbf{x'} | A | \mathbf{x''} \rangle \langle \mathbf{x''} | \Pi | \Psi\rangle = \int d\mathbf{x'} \Psi^*(-\mathbf{x'})A\Psi(-\mathbf{x'})$$

where in the last step I've made use of the orthogonality of position states and the Hermiticity of the parity operator.

So either way is valid (although the relation $U^{-1}AU = \pm A$ *is independent of basis*). In the same way that we can speak of time-evolved operators with time-independent kets in the Schrödinger picture and time-evolved kets with time-independent operators in the Heisenberg picture, we can choose to transform the "inputs" or the operator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that you can think of a unitary operator transforming another operator, with the expression $U^{-1}AU$.  Will think more on your other points..

Comment: It makes more sense now.  If we consider $U^{-1}AU$ to be
"moving into the frame created by the unitary transformation,
for example the  'mirror image of reality'  created by the
parity operator, then performing the original operation $A$
in that  'alternate reality',  then switching back to the
original  'home coordinates'  frame",  then it makes sense
to call this transforming the operator itself.  Thank you
for clearing that up.

Comment: I believe that in going from

$\langle \Psi | \Pi^{-1} A \Pi | \Psi \rangle$

to

$\int d\mathbf{x'} d\mathbf{x''} \langle \Psi | \Pi^{-1} |
 \mathbf{x'} \rangle \langle \mathbf{x'} | A | \mathbf{x''} \rangle
 \langle \mathbf{x''} | \Pi | \Psi \rangle$

you are just saying that to evaluate expectation value
in the position basis you have to stick those
$| \mathbf{x'} \rangle \langle \mathbf{x'} |$
$| \mathbf{x''} \rangle \langle \mathbf{x''} |$
in those places.

Comment: Once you've done that, then resolving the right hand side
you are just noting that  "Clearly, applying
$| \mathbf{x''} \rangle \langle \mathbf{x''} |$  to the
ket  $(\Pi | \Psi \rangle)$  is clearly just going to be
the position representation of  $|\Psi\rangle$  but with
its input position mirrored"  (that's what the parity operator
does).  Hence, $\Psi(-\mathbf{x''})$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Well, let me clarify that the parity operator, because it's Hermitian, can work on the $\langle \mathbf{x''} \mid$ bra to give $\langle -\mathbf{x''} \mid$, and when you take its inner product with $\mid \Psi \rangle$ you get $\Psi(-\mathbf{x''})$

Comment: I now understand that, as well as what you meant by
using the orthogonality of position states:  $\int d\mathbf{x'}
d\mathbf{x''}  \langle\Psi|\Pi^{-1}|\mathbf{x'}\rangle
\langle|\mathbf{x'}|A|\mathbf{x''}\rangle \langle\mathbf{x''}|
\Pi|\Psi\rangle$  being a double integral, there are tons of
terms of the form $c_0\langle\mathbf{x'}=(777.88,9,-10)|A
 (c_1|\mathbf{x''}=(-56.5,-1,22.22)\rangle)$
for example, but they all evaluate to 0 except when $\mathbf{x'}
= \mathbf{x''}$.  Thanks a lot for the educational exposition!